# How Do I Access Google Sheets from Compute VM?

Tags: google-sheets, google-compute-engine, google-sheets-api, google-authentication, service-accounts

I am trying to use the Google Sheets API from a Google Cloud VM to access data on my Google Drive. I have the API running fine locally, both in scripts and in Jupyter. I can't figure out how to set my permissions up to make this work on the VM.

I can SSH to the VM and run a script from the command line, but I don't know how to validate the credentials without a web browser. I follow the "Please visit this URL to authorize this application" URL, click through authorization, but then get a "this site can't be reached" error. (The unreachable URL is "http://localhost:40633/...")

(I have all permissions and I've tried following the directions for using a service account on the VM, but I'm apparently too stupid to make that work. If this is the way to go, I will keep at it, but I wanted to see if there was a way to make the browser authorization work before I spent more time on that.)

Comment: Why don't you authorise on your local machine and then copy over the token file?

Comment: wow it really was that simple wasn't it. thanks!